# Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call To A Member Function Fetch() On Boolean

Tags: php, pdo

After doing researches, i did not found any solution. please help me. 
My database is like that:

[image]

```
  $article = array($_GET['id']);
  $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=matr;charset=utf8', 'matr', 'vicecity');
  $articletitre = $bdd->prepare('SELECT titre FROM articles WHERE id=?');
  $articletitre = $articletitre->execute($article);
  $articletitre = $articletitre->fetch();
```

And i have this error

> Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call To A Member Function Fetch() On
>   Boolean

Comment: After defining `$bdd`, add `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` - this will set PDO to throw exceptions, which you can't ignore - that means that any errors will be displayed and logged (if you enable logging of PHP errors).

Comment: I added your line and nothing more outputs

Comment: What about `print_r($articletitre->errorInfo());`?

Comment: You __overwrite__ `$articletitre`, that's all

Comment: Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call To A Member Function ErrorInfo() On Boolean

Comment: At first it is object of type PDOStatement and then just a boolean value.

Comment: @u_mulder Oh wow, can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in this statement,

```
$articletitre = $articletitre->execute($article);
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`->execute()` returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE` after executing the prepared statement. That's why `$articletitre->fetch();` is failing because you're trying to execute `->fetch()` method on a boolean. So your code should be like this:

```
$article = array($_GET['id']);
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=matr;charset=utf8', 'matr', 'vicecity');
$articletitre = $bdd->prepare('SELECT titre FROM articles WHERE id=?');
$articletitre->execute($article);
$articletitre = $articletitre->fetch();
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php